# Xml not well formad error

Tags: android, xml

ok, i am just starting to learn how to develop an app, I'm doing the right thing (or so I hope) by having a look and learning from android itself. I have spent a while looking around on the web and not been able to find an answer for an issue this early in the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html#Buttonhttp://)

However i cant even get past the third part of the lesson as it keeps coming up with an error.

here is my code for reference:

main activity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        android:inputType="text" />
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
</resources>
```

the specific error im getting is : "error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)   activity_main.xml   /MyFirstApp/res/layout  line 6  Android AAPT Problem"

Comment: You missed to close your first item in `xml`: the `LinearLayout`

Comment: you shouldn't use the word retarded.

Comment: that is the basic problem we have... we need to learn xml and java before jumping in to android development. one can't win a war until he doesn't know how to use the sword and the shield.

Comment: i had tried closing the statement already, however didnt space it after the "" and for some reason that just gave me a massive bunch of errors :S cheers for the help though

Comment: All you had to do was copy and paste the code. You copied it wrong somehow, and you're wondering why it didn't work?

Comment: what is the point of copying and pasting if you are trying to learn something? and i cant yet, there is a minimum amount of time before you can accept an answer.

Comment: Maybe, @mikeyaworski wants to say when you copy/paste your code on SO, you see the colors are not in a good formatting (blue, red, ...) like  other answers, so there is something wrong :)

Comment: @Fllo I meant in his actual code. But yes, that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" > <!-- you forgot this ">" -->
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    android:inputType="text" />
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> **Error parsing XML** means that there is an error in your xml files
>   **not well-formed** your files have something wrong in its build
>   **activity_main.xml** which xml
>   **/MyFirstApp/res/layout** where in my package
>   **line 6** you know everything ;)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

With this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
```